# Matlab - Matching nominal values to numeric values for a bar plot?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 variables, one is USA/Non-USA (origin of 35 cars), the second is horsepower (of 35 cars).
I need to create a bar and errorbar plot for the mean horsepower of each option of the first variable, so 2 bars of the mean horsepowes.

The bar function will not pair nominal values to numeric ones.

Thanks in advance for the help, I just started Matlab and am a bit lost!

Comment: post the code you wrote so far.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what I have to do but I tried this:

figure(3)
bar(Origin1970Merged,Horsepower(1:35,:))

of course that didn't work.. and somewhere the mean function needs to appear but i don't know where :(

Comment: Rosie, you nee to post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example in order to get some help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Rosie Please verify [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29803309/802378) and clarify what the error plot is expected to be

Comment: Ander I don't have a code as of yet, sorry :(
kris thank you! My usa indicator is not binary, it's nominal with two categories, either USA or Non-USA. How do I turn it to a binary array? Thanks!

Comment: Kris your code worked! Thank you so much! I need to add the St Dv errorbars now

Comment: @Rosie Good to hear :) I don't understand what you mean by std dv error bars. Do you mean Box and Whisker plot?

Comment: I totally fnished the code and managed it at the end. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `usa` indicator is denoted by a binary (1 for usa, 0 for non-use), you can use the following. You can then aggregate the classes using `accumarray`. Then you can plot using `bar`.

```
% Initialize Toy Data
usa = [0 0 1 1]';
hp = [5 15 10 20]';

% Grab Unique Classes
[u,~,c] = unique( usa );

% Aggregate By Unique Classes, m is the mean for each class
m = accumarray( c, hp, size(u), @(x) mean(x) );

% Plot bar graph
bar(u,m)
```

I'm not sure what error plot you're referring to, please clarify. You can use this data for any plot.